# Send data to a url instead of saving when scrapy is done

Tags: scrapy

I have been reading a lot on scrapy and have my code done to scrape a printer web page to get the information I want.

Currently I can run the script with `-o data.json`

What I am looking for is one of two things.

1) Instead of saving as a file, send the json to an endpoint as POST request to an API.  I have read on item pipeline and know I can set a number to batch things (dont know it fully) but I just want to send all the json at once when the scrape is over.

2) if 1 is not possible, is it possible to run scrapy from another python script and get the data back in there.  From there I can do whatever I need to with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried storing data in MySQL instead? and later syncing it over other server(s).

Here is a tweak, just in case you'd still like to use your idea:

First, enable the pipeline in the 'spider':

```
'ITEM_PIPELINES' : {
    'yourproject.pipelines.YourProjectPipeline': 300
},
```

Then add this (pseudo) code in item pipeline 'pipelines.py':

```
class YourProjectPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # this will make an object with multiple json string(s)
        self.json = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.json.append( item['varilable_which_holds_data'] )

    def __del__(self):
        # this def is called when crawler ends therefore
        # this is the place where you need to send data to API
        pass
```